# Proof verification- $ \sigma $ - Algebra, Algebra, Ring

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I want to prove following  for a set $ X \neq \emptyset $ :
$ M \subset P(X) $, where $ P(X) $ is the power set.

1) Any Ring is an Algebra

2) Any Algebra is a Ring

3) Any Ring is a $ \sigma $ -Algebra

4) Any Algebra is a $ \sigma $- Algebra

5) Any $ \sigma $- Algebra is an Algebra

For a set $ X \neq \emptyset $, $M$ is

a) A Ring if

- $ \emptyset \in M$
- $ A,B \in M \rightarrow A \cup B \in M $
- $ A,B \in M \rightarrow B \backslash A \in M $

b) An Algebra, if $ M$ Ring , and $ X \in M $

c) A $ \sigma $-Algebra if

- $ X \in M $
- $ A \in M \rightarrow X \backslash A \in M $
- $ (A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in M  \rightarrow \cup_{i=0}^{ \infty} A_i \in M $

---

for 1)
For $ A \subset X $ is M:={ \emptyset   , A} a Ring, but for $ A \neq X$ not an Algebra.

2)
let be $ A,B \in M $

$ A \backslash  B =  ( A^c \cup B )^c \in M $
So M is also a ring.

3)
I guess I can use the same example as for 1)?

4) let be $ X= \mathbb{N} , M:= \{ A \subset X : A $ or $ A^c $ finite $\}$
is this a right example for an Alegbra , which is not a s.Algeba?

5)
$A,B \in M $

$ X= X \backslash \emptyset \in M $

$ A\backslash B = A \cap B^c  = ( A^c \cup B)^c \in M $

any union you can discribe as :
$ A \cup B = A \cup B \cup \emptyset \cup ...\emptyset \in M $

so any s. Algebra is also an Algebra.

are my arguments correct and formally right? any adjustments?
Appreciate any of your help !

Comment: What is the role of the set $\;X\;$ in all those question ...??

Comment: it's a random set..if that's what you mean.?

Comment: Do you see how to go from boolean algebra on $M $ to $\sigma$-algebra on $M$  ? $A . B = A \cap B$ and $A + B =...$